# How to create offsetting lines that draw across the screen in Monogame?

Tags: c#, xna, shaders, monogame

I'm trying to create an effect on the screen like the gif below. Basically lines that are offset by 1 pixel draw across the screen from either side which then eventually creates a solid color.

I'm using Monogame for this and I'd prefer a shader doing it. The only resolution I'd need to support is 240x160.

I've delved a bit into a [scanline shader](https://github.com/libretro/common-shaders/blob/master/scanline.cg) to see if I could adapt it, but so far it doesn't look like it's going to work.

[image: Line Screen Effect]